# Combining row names in extensive dataframe while keeping data associated with specific rows

Tags: r, plyr, sqldf

I have an extensive dataframe consisting of the names of beers and their review's there are several repeats for each beer does anyone have any suggestions on how i can combine them to reduce each review set  to one listing of the beer name and average of its overall reviews

ie

```
   {original table}
beername         overallreview
Blue moon              4
Blue moon              4
Blue moon              3
Blue moon              1
Blue moon              5
Blue moon              3


  {operation results in}
beername         overallreview
Blue moon             3.333
```

here is what i have tried so far

```
library(plyr)
library(sqldf)
# Load Packages plyr & sqldf
beerdata <- read.csv(file.choose())
#Select data from csv file 
summary(beerdata)
#Summary of data

best_beer <- beerdata[,c("reviewoverall","beername")]

refined_best <- ddply(best_beer, .(beername), function(x) {
  if(nrow(x) > 1)
    return(data.frame("beername" = unique(x$beername), "mean_ratings" =      mean(x$reviewoverall)))
})
```

Thusfar this code only crashes r ^^^^

Comment: you should provide the code for your example dataset!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ddply(best_beer, .(beername), summarise,
    mean_ratings = mean(reviewoverall))
```

*should* work.

Comment: Thankyou so much Ben! Could i also do more means following the mean ratings ?